# Does `use-package` reduce startup time? If so, how?

Tags: use-package, start-up

My understanding of Emacs's package management is that Emacs automatically loads all installed packages.

`use-package` itself is a package, which only becomes usable after `(package-initialize)`, at which point all packages have already been loaded.

I was just wondering how exactly `use-package` reduce startup time for Emacs? Can anybody explain this at a high level?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't do anything you couldn't be doing without it; so the answer might well be that it doesn't improve performance at all.  It could vary from user to user.

It *does* encapsulate some mechanisms (which you might already be using) for making good use of autoloading and deferred evaluation of code, in order to *avoid loading libraries any earlier than necessary*; so users who weren't doing that might well see noticeable improvements to their start-up times after converting their configs to `use-package`.

> My understanding of Emacs's package management is that Emacs automatically loads all installed packages.

Only the autoloads file for each package is `load`ed during package initialisation.  If you were to `load` each individual elisp library provided by each package, that would take a lot longer.